# Converting If/Else to Switch

Tags: php

How do I convert the below to a switch instead of If/Else? I read that if I have more than `if/elseif/else` that i should use a switch instead

```
 $domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain1.com" && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ab03') !== false ) {
        codeblock();
        $tlink = "http://google.com";
    } elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain1.com" && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ab05') !== false ) {
        $tlink = "http://cnn.com";
} elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain2.com" && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ab05') !== false ) {
        $tlink = "http://yahoo.com";
} elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain3.com" && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ab05') !== false ) {
        $tlink = "http://example.com";
    } else {
        $tlink = "http://cbs.com";
    }
```

Comment: `switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) { case 'domain1.com': ... break; ... }`

Comment: @Rizier123 interesting option, but someone commented that it would be better to go with if/else.. is there a reason y?

Comment: @JoeBobby From my perspective i also would use if statements in your case, because it's easier to write and read and since PHP doesn't create Jump tables for switch statements you don't get much performance improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You could have found this yourself in a 5 sec Google search...

```
switch($i){
   case 0:
   break;
}
```

Simply replace $i with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to compare and 0 with the wanted value example `domain1.com`.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

However the `switch` is not really adapted to your code as you have multiple conditions in your `if`. Since the second condition seems to be always the same, you could simply put the `switch` in the `if` of the second condition or use the clause inside each case but this would be redundant code.

Comment: I think he knows the syntax, wanted for someone to help him set up the clauses.

Comment: Then use this clauses inside the specific case. But OP says "I read that if I have more than if/elseif/else that i should use a switch instead" so this looks like for syntax request.

Comment: @Mr.Smith I have some switches that i have used in the past, but the part im confused about is making it work with $_Server and strpos

Answer (score 1):

try use code

```
    switch ($domain) {
    case 'domain1.com':
        if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ab03') !== false) {
            codeblock();
            $tlink = "http://google.com";         
        } elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ab05') !== false ) {
            $tlink = "http://cnn.com";
        }
    break;
    case 'domain2.com':
        if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ab05') !== false) {
            $tlink = "http://yahoo.com";
        }
    break;
    case 'domain3':
        if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ab05') !== false ) {
            $tlink = "http://example.com";
        }
    break;
    default:
        $tlink = "http://cbs.com";
    break;  
}
```